# How to map IEnumerable to List using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to map IEnumerable to List. I am not sure how to get it work. Here is what I have tried so far.

I am getting an error "Custom configuration for members is only supported for top-level individual members on a type."

```
Source: IEnumerable<Source>
Target: List<Target>

AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(sourceIEnum, TargetList);

Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Source>, List<Target>>()
    .ForMember(f => f, mp => mp.MapFrom(
                                    mfrom => mfrom.Select(s => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(s, new Target())
                                ).ToList())
              );

Mapper.CreateMap<Source, Target>()
    .ForMember(f => f.TargetPropertyA, mp => mp.MapFrom(mfrom => mfrom.FromA.Value))
    .ForMember(f => f.TargetPropertyB, mp => mp.MapFrom(mfrom => mfrom.FromB.Value))
    .ForMember(f => f.TargetPropertyC, mp => mp.MapFrom(mfrom => mfrom.FromC.Value))
    .ForMember(f => f.InnerObjectTarget, mp => mp.MapFrom(
                                    mfrom => mfrom.Select(s => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(s, new InnerObjectTarget())
                                ).ToList())
              );    

Mapper.CreateMap<SourceInner, TargetInner>()
        .ForMember(f => f.TargetInnerPropA, m => m.MapFrom(source => source.InnerA))
        .ForMember(f => f.TargetInnerPropB, m => m.MapFrom(source => source.InnerB))
        .ForMember(f => f.TargetInnerPropC, m => m.MapFrom(source => source.InnerC));
```

Answer (score 6):

There a several ways to map an `IEnumerable<Source>` to an `IEnumerable<Target>`. I'll show the three most convenient ones.

Taking the [AdventureWorks database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587) (2008R2) as an example, I defined three DTO classes:

```
class ProductModelDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductDto> Products { get; set; }
}

class ProductDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductReviewDto> ProductReviews { get; set; }
}

class ProductReviewDto
{
    public string ReviewerName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the only mapping I defined:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductModelDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Product, ProductDto>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.Number, m => m.MapFrom(p => p.ProductNumber));
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductReview, ProductReviewDto>()
      .ForMember(dto => dto.Email, m => m.MapFrom(pr => pr.EmailAddress));
```

Just a query:

```
// A ProductModel having a Product with ProductReviews
var query = db.ProductModels.Where(pm => pm.ProductModelID == 64);
```

Now the most convenient ways, in my opinion, to map the source `ProductModel`s to `IEnumerable<ProductModelDto>` are these three:

```
1. query.Select(Mapper.Map<ProductModelDto>)
2. Mapper.Map<List<ProductModelDto>>(query)
3. query.ProjectTo<ProductModelDto>() (Project().To<> prior to v. 4.1.0)
```

And if you do `ToList()`, you've mapped `IEnumerable` to `List`.

The output is the same for all three alternatives:

```
- HL Mountain Pedal
  - HL Mountain Pedal; PD-M562
    - David; david@graphicdesigninstitute.com
    - Jill; jill@margiestravel.com
```

As you see, AutoMapper doesn't need explicit mapping definitions for the `IEnumerable`s. Not for the top level and not for the nested collections. It also maps a nested collection when the names are identical in the source and target classes and a mapping is defined for the elements in the collection.

Case **3** is a special case. It projects the `IQueryable` to the target, which is still an `IQueryable`. Predicates applied *after* the mapping are still translated to SQL and the query tries to select only the fields from the database that are necessary for projection. The latter doesn't always succeed when DTOs are nested though, as in this case. Linq-to SQL appeared to execute two queries with option 3 (but three for 1 and 2).

Comment: number 1 in your list, doesn't seem to work, have you missed something in the syntax there?  I was returning IEnumerable... (on the source)

Comment: @Choco. Please be more specific.

Comment: query.Select(Mapper.Map<ProductModelDto>)   I'm only asking if you missed some soft brackets or something, that's all... sort of a double check. As I'm trying to get an IEnumerable list (source) to  convert over.

Comment: *deosn't seem to work* suggest you get some error. The syntax is OK, it's equivalent to `query.Select(x => Mapper.Map<ProductModelDto>(x))`.

Answer (score 2):

As long as **Source** to **Target** mapping is defined, you don't need to define **`IEnumerable<Source>`** to **`List<Target>`** mapping explicitly.

Automapper is smart enough to map the basic collections automatically **(List, IEnumerable, Collection etc.)** if the collection element types are mapped. so remove all code between collection mapping and try again.

This snippet..

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Source>, List<Target>>()
    .ForMember(f => f, mp => mp.MapFrom(
                                    mfrom => mfrom.Select(s => AutoMapper.Mapper.Map(s, new Target())
                                ).ToList())
              );
```

Comment: how will map this, my code below   var EmployeeDetailDTO = new EmployeeDetailDTO();  var EmpList1  = _context.EmployeeDetail.ToList().AsEnumerable(); EmployeeDetailDTO = Mapper.Map<EmployeeDetail, EmployeeDetailDTO>(EmpList1);  getting error while impliment like this